# If click on checked list item prevent uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want is, when the list item is checked, and you click on the checked item you can not uncheck them.

Thanks for any help :)

```
$(".collectioncontainer ul li").click(function(){
    $('.collectioncontainer ul li.checked').not(this).removeClass('checked');
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no point in using `.hasClass()` to check the existence of class on clicked element. use `.addClass()` as you only want the class to be added:

```
$(".collectioncontainer ul li").click(function(){
  $('.collectioncontainer ul li.checked').not(this).removeClass('checked');
  $(this).addClass('checked');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need event handlers to do something a single time, the [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method is useful:

```
$(".collectioncontainer ul li").one('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('checked');
})
```

Using `addClass` makes it explicit you only want a class to be included by the action, and might guard against accidentally removing the class with `toggleClass`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by checking using [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) method instead:

```
$(".collectioncontainer ul li").click(function(){
    if( !$( this ).hasClass( 'checked' ) ) {
        $( this ).addClass( 'checked' );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply do not remove that class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('checked');
  });
});
```

```css
li.checked {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want your checkboxes to be checked the first time and keep them from being unchecked, use an event listener:

```
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="bob" value="I'm bob">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var c=document.getElementById("checkbox");
    c.addEventListener("click",function(event_){
        this.checked=true;
    });
</script>
```

I know you're using JQuery, but I'm sure you can easily see what the plain JavaScript does, the concept should hold true. I'm not so great at JQuery, but I think you were using a click event listener, anyway. Hope this helps!